# Change size of Progress Bar

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I have progress bar but dots too small, how I can make it bigger?
I didnt found any property witch can change size of dots. Height/Width change onlly area where dots can move

`Xaml` code

```
<Grid // here width ="2560" height="1600"
  <ProgressBar
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        IsIndeterminate="True"
        Visibility="{Binding MainInstance.Loading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid
```

Comment: ProgressBar blocks size are underlying to width/height.

Comment: @Joel changed width/height from Auto(300/4) to 1000/1000 and nothing changed dots just moving in different zone but dots small

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options to solve this, it's up to you which one you pick:

- Change the default style of `ProgressBar` and increase the `Ellipse` `Width` and `Height` properties. You can do this in Blend or by copying the style from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic\generic.xaml

- Use a `ViewBox` control to wrap around the `ProgressBar`. This control resizes all content to the available size.
- Create a templated control with your own template settings properties.

I have created a small [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/bartlannoeye-com/2016-10-ProgressBarTemplateSettings) to show you the code for all possibilities.

[image]

Comment: It's better than me.

Comment: It's better than me.

Comment: I have trouble with ViewBox. When I make big Width and small Height my circles are bigger than ViewBox Height how fix it? I want it looks like in your example

Comment: You can see the code on GitHub (I'm not on Win10 right now). This is an [explanation](https://blog.udemy.com/wpf-viewbox/) on how ViewBox works in WPF (very similar in UWP). But editing the template is in my opinion a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to change ProgressBar's dots size is to use ScaleTransform:

```
<ProgressBar ...>
    <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
    </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
</ProgressBar>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case (WinUI3 SDK1.1.0) I have had a thin 1px-line and it helped me to use the MinHeight property instead of the Height. I hope that MinHeight also will help you with the dotted line.

```
<StackPanel BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="LightGray" Padding="12">
    <muxc:ProgressBar 
    Value="{x:Bind Path=XamlProductionViewModel.XamlCurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}" 
    IsIndeterminate="{x:Bind Path=XamlProductionViewModel.XamlIsIndeterminate, Mode=OneWay}"
    Visibility="{x:Bind Path=XamlProductionViewModel.XamlProgressVisibility, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
    Foreground="AliceBlue" 
    Background="Transparent" 
    Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="100" 
    BorderThickness="0" 
    Margin="0" 
    MinHeight="25" 
    Width="300"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

ProgressRing not support any property to change the dots width and height ,and when the ProgressRing have a bigger space the dots will be biggest.
You can use the Grid which get a ProgressBar and the Grid is permanent position.
You use the `Grid.Row="0"        Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"` and you should write the code in Grid.You should give the Grid big  space.
ProgressBar should use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and the same of VerticalAlignment.You have a big width and big height the dots will have a big width and big height.

```
    <ProgressRing Margin="10,10,10,10"
                 IsActive="True"
                 Visibility="{x:Bind View.Visibility,Mode=OneWay}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

I write in the top Grid.You can see my app's ProgressRing have a big dots.

http://jycloud.9uads.com/web/GetObject.aspx?filekey=16bcfec973e910632e04b3990c274a1c

Comment: Grid cell (0,1) have a lot of space and I updated my code. Is it right? But my dots still small

Comment: You try set Grid width=100 or bigger.And the ProgressRing should set HorizontalAlignment and verticalAlignment to Stretch and not any width,height and margin.

Comment: I did that, my grid is 2560/1600. And you can see my XAML code. But dots small and 1 more its not a ring just a line because IsIndeterminate="True"

Comment: Do you sure your ProgressRing's Grid is 2560/1600 or you try to set your ProgressRing to 2560/1600

Comment: Grid.Row="0" and Grid.Column="1" is make the ProgressRing's width not same as Grid.

Comment: yes ok. But this cell take over 80% of screen space

Comment: ProgressRing's width and height can be set.You can easy to make it big as you Top Grid.

Comment: You can set ProgressRing to top Grid.

Comment: what you mean top Grid?  I have only one Grid

Comment: The top grid is your page content.

Comment: yes it is. I'll delete column and row and try again

Comment: The only Grid is the top Grid.And you set ProgressRing to top Grid and dont set the margin and  the code is ` <ProgressBar  IsIndeterminate="True"  Visibility="{Binding MainInstance.Loading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />`

Comment: Hi SmiLe, you see the difference between ProgressRing and ProgressBar?! Just in case